# Can jqplot show different series' legends in different locations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have a graph (http://jsfiddle.net/CfVZP/12/) with several series where the y-axis data is on two different scales. I'm using the yaxis for one scale and the y2axis for the other. I'd like to be able to display the legend for the series using the yaxis on the left side of the graph (location: 'nw') and the legends for the series using the y2axis on the right side (location: 'ne'). Is there a way to set different legend properties for different series?

Something like:

```
{series: [
    showMarker: true,
    color: "#00FF00",
    legend: {           // This doesn't actually work.
        location: 'ne', // I'm looking for a substitute
    }                   // for this functionality.
],
// Additional series with different legend locations
}
```

It doesn't seem possible to do this using the standard legend options (I tried playing with the position and the EnhancedLegendRenderere column options), but I was wondering if there is a different plugin that might be able to make this happen, or some other option that can be altered to cause the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is going to be possible. Looking at the jqplot source code, each plot holds only a single `Legend` object - for this to work you would most likely need it to hold an array of them.

Is there a particular reason you would like to do this? It would be a little unusual to have a plot with multiple legends. Would it not suffice to have a single legend but give each series a good, descriptive name?

Comment: It's just to show which plots belong to which y axis. Just a nice visual clue we wanted to include. If I can't find a solution we probably will just go with a single, well labeled, legend like you suggested (which is what we're currently doing.)